# Xcode Rotations, AutoLayouts

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I'm learning OOP and I'm using Xcode with Swift. I'm learning using a book of Apress, but I don't understand a simple step. The instructions says this:

> "Hold down the Shift key and select Top Space To Layout Guide and
>   Center Horizontally in container in the pop-up, and then press
>   return."

But the pop-up doesn't appear. Can someone help me please?

Comment: This is not really a programming issue...

Comment: @UweAllner: according to the [guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it is OK to ask about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: But there is an _interface builder_ tag : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

You can set the constraints in multiple ways within the Interface Builder.

In your case, you could select your view (button, label, ...) and do one of the following :

1. ctrl+clic and drag on another view (not with the shift key) to make the pop-up appear :

   1. [image: drag]
   2. [image: pop-up]
2. do it with the *menus* at the bottom right :

   1. [image: menus]
   2. [image: horizontal]
   3. [image: top layout guide]

Let me know if it helped.